# Cannot put a new List inside method brackets

Tags: java, list

***Senario:***

So I am trying to simplify the usage of setting a lot of `TextViews` invisible by making a lot a lines of code into one, so decided to make a method that gets  `List<TextView>` and turns them all invisible. I made a test Class to show the error. (Problem bellow)

**Method:**

```
 private void makeTextViewsInvisible(List<TextView> listOfTextViews){
    int i= 0;
    while(i < listOfTextViews.size()){
        listOfTextViews.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Using the method:**

```
makeTextViewsInvisible(new List<t1,t2,t3>()) ;
            //Dose'nt work?
            //I don't want to define : (List<TextView> a  = new ...) And add TextViews manually (a.add(TextView1)...)
            //I want to add all three TextViews in one line of code inside the brackets
```

Problem is, that I cannot make a `new List` inside the brackets, I need to make a whole new `List` and add all the `TextViews` *manually* (By using `List.add();`), witch dosent simplify my code. Any way to  make a new List inside the bracket it self?

Comment: You could a) use Arrays.asList b) learn about var-args.

Comment: I dont really know what you mean. Could you show with some code?

Comment: makeTextViewsInvisible(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3))

Comment: The code dosent gives errors, lets see if it complies...

Comment: The code works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax

> makeTextViewsInvisible(new List())

is incorrect.
You clearly do not understand the syntax of List initialization.
If you want to insert three elements to the list of a given type (in your case it'll be `List<TextViews>` I believe) you have to initialize it (the list of type `TextViews`). Note that you probably don't want to instantiate a List, because it is an interface and you would have to implement every method of List interface, such as `add(), get(), indexOf()` etc. I suggest that you pass the `ArrayList` as your function argument. Let's say that `t1,t2,t3` are already defined objects of type `TextViews`. To instantiate `ArrayList<TextViews>` you need the following syntax:

```
ArrayList<TextViews> exampleList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3));
```

You have to pass an array as a constructor of a list, which you can easily do with `Arrays.asList()` static method. With that said, syntax of your method invocation would look like this:

```
makeTextViewsInvisible(new ArrayList<TextViews>(Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3));
```

Comment: Well explained, and you provided a better answer than in the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that if you would use this library...
[org.apache.commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html)

Then it should be possible to call your method like this.

```
List<String> newList = ListUtils.union(list1,list2);


makeTextViewsInvisible(ListUtils.union(t1,t2,t3));
```

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html